# Joda-time: First day in this year's ISO week 1

Tags: java, jodatime

I would like to find out the date of the Monday in this year's ISO week 1 (For 2009 this would be Monday, Dec 29 2008).

I'm sure that [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/cal_iso.html) can handle this, but I just can't figure out the API (maybe it's just too late).

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
DateMidnight date = new DateMidnight().withWeekOfWeekyear(1).withDayOfWeek(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, Blake! Exactly what I was looking for. 

For the archive, "withWeekOfWeekYear()" must be spelled "withWeekOfWeekyear()" (lowercase y).

Comment: **NOTE:** This answer uses classes and methods *no longer recommended* by the Joda-Time team. See the [correct answer by shaILU](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22334471/642706). To quote the [Release Notes](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/upgradeto230.html): `DateMidnight … This class is flawed in concept … Replace … with LocalDate … [or] DateTime … [using] … withTimeAtStartOfDay() method`.  ( [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) or [DateTime.withTimeAtStartOfDay()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) )

Answer (score 25):

The `DateMidnight` API mentioned in the other answer is now deprecated, use below:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime().dayOfYear().withMinimumValue().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```